# Unable to Launch Safaridriver

Tags: safaridriver

**OS:** macOS Sierra

**Browser:** Safari v11.0.3

**Problem**: Cannot launch safaridriver even though safaridriver --enable has been run.

**Error**

'safaridriver could not launch because it is not configured correctly or you need to authenticate. Re-run safaridriver(1) and pass the '--enable' flag to configure and/or authenticate. For more information, consult the safaridriver(1) man page.'

**Error Log**

```
qa01:~ svctest$ safaridriver --enable
Password:
qa01:~ svctest$ safaridriver -p 0
ERROR: safaridriver could not launch because it is not configured
correctly or you need to authenticate. Re-run safaridriver(1) and
pass the '--enable' flag to configure and/or authenticate.
For more information, consult the safaridriver(1) man page.
qa01:~ svctest$
```

Comment: Have you found a solution? I met the same problem, after running the same command with a non-root user.

Answer (score 3):

you need to run it as a superuser, that will correctly save new configuration:
         `sudo safaridriver --enable`

Comment: sudo safaridriver --enable was tried with no success.

Answer (score 1):

Many bugs have been fixed in `safaridriver --enable` since this question was asked, including fixes for running under sudo. Please close the question.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is the logged in account privileges. Even though an admin password was used to enable the Safari driver the logged in account was not an admin.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
sudo -u <your user> safaridriver --enable
```

After that you can see in Safari menu `Develop->Allow Remote Automation` is checked